# How to execute a migration?

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm trying to use the Migrate API module to implement an ETL for some of the content of my Drupal 8 website, but [the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/executing-migrations) doesn't explain how to execute the migration once everything has been set up. It only explains how to execute the migration using some contributed modules but not how to execute it using the Drupal API.

How do I programmatically execute migrations from a module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drupal 8 Migrations are plugins. So you can create instance and execute like this:

```
<?php

use Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutable;
use Drupal\migrate\MigrateMessage;


$migration_id = 'MIGRATION_ID';
$migration = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.migration')->createInstance($migration_id);
$executable = new MigrateExecutable($migration, new MigrateMessage());
$executable->import();
```